# Alternative reference to Davenport's Analytic Methods for geometry of numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, geometry-of-numbers

I was wondering if someone would be willing to suggest an alternative reference to Davenport's book Analytic Methods for Diophantine Equations and Diophantine Equations. I like the book but I would like to read up from a different source some theorems about the geometry of numbers which are important to analytic number theorists. I apologize if the question is too broad. Thanks!

Comment: Cassels 'Introduction to the Geometry of Numbers' is the classical reference for this area. Or, depending what you're looking for, chaper 2 of Tao and Vu's 'Additive Combinatorics' might be a more modern treatment. It's also worth looking at Vaughan's 'Hardy-Littlewood Method' for more on the circle method.

Comment: Ah, I see. I shall check these out, especially Cassels. However, I think Vaughan doesn't talk about the geometry of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some classical books on the subject, I use them all:

- Cassels: An introduction to the geometry of numbers
- Gruber-Lekkerkerker: Geometry of numbers
- Siegel-Chandrasekharan: Lectures on the geometry of numbers

Comment: Thank you so much for the list of references. I found the third one particularly well-motivated. Also, Taylor and Fröhlich's Algebraic Number Theory also had a few things that I was looking for in geometry of numbers (removed previous comment about Cassels and Fröhlich which is a different text).